# Target Label Then Replace Text Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, innerhtml

we have a booking system plugin that has an "Email" field that we need to change to "Agents Email". I need to know how to change the "Email" label to "Agents Email" using inline JS. This is tough because the field has no ID or Class attached.
Go to https://www.rudyspest.com/calendar-a/ then select a date and time and you will be presented with the form. The Email field needs to change...

Here's some code I've been playing with, feel free to start from scratch or change this:

```
<script>
    var div = document.querySelectorAll(".t.tbk-field-text label");

    for(var i=0; i < div.length; i++){

        var div1 = div[i].innerHTML;
        if (div1 == "Email") {
            div[i].innerHTML = "Agents Email";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does its job pretty well but using `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to check the text of label elements and using `replace` to replace `Email` with `Agents Email` would be better ideas since the label could eventually contain other empty elements as well.

Here is my approach:

```js
const labelEles = document.querySelectorAll(".tbk-reservation-form label");

if (labelEles.length) {
  for(let i = 0; i < labelEles.length; i++){
    const curLabelEle = labelEles[i];
    if (curLabelEle.innerText === "Email")
      curLabelEle.innerHTML = curLabelEle.innerHTML.replace("Email", "Agents Email")
  }
}
```